# Массивы в си

Tags: c

Дан массив из n чисел типа int. Нужно удалить повторяющиеся числа.
Например,если у нас есть 11 3 21 1234 12 12 45 3 12, нужно получить другой массив, где будут 11 3 21 1234 12 45

Comment: Максимальная величина числа, требования к памяти, времени работы...

Comment: Прекрасное учебное задание. Вы ведь не хотите, чтобы мы за вас его выполнили?

Попробуйте сами. Для начала составьте алгоритм, попробуйте его реализовать, протестируйте на различных входных данных, отладьте и устраните ошибки.

Удачи!

Comment: Вы ведь не хотите, чтобы мы за вас его выполнили?
Конечно, не хочет - для того и написал.

Answer (score 1):

Да простит меня [@VladD](/users/10105/vladd), но вот: (в оправдание могу заявить, что проверок тут явно не хватает)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int n, maxval = 10000, i, j;
    unsigned char *bits;
    int *m;
    printf("Введите длину массива чисел:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    m = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    bits = malloc(maxval/8);
    for(i=0; i < maxval/8; i++) bits[i]=0;
    printf("Введите массив чисел:\n");
    for(i=0, j=0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", m+j);
        if(m[j] > maxval) {
            int k;
            bits = realloc(bits, (m[j]+7)/8);
            for(k = maxval/8; k < (m[j]+7)/8; k++) bits[k]=0;
            maxval = (m[j]+7)/8 * 8;
        }
        if(!(bits[m[j]/8] & (1 << m[j]%8))) {
            bits[m[j]/8] |= 1 << m[j]%8;
            j++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<j; i++) printf("%d ", m[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1. Если ТС разберётся в том, зачем нужен realloc, ему зачёт :-)